# CSS - display: flex and position: absoulte moves anchor point

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex element and three children. The second child should overlap the first using position absolute, like this:

**Expected:**

[image: Expected]

Note that the second child should be **on top** of the first child, not next to it.

However, setting `display: flex` on the parent seems to shift the anchor or reference point of the absolute element to start of the div. The actual outcome is this:

**Actual result:**

[image: Actual]

Putting the second child in the first or third element is not an option, because they have `overflow: scroll`. So is using any other `display` property on the parent, because my layout relies on `display: flex`. I know these solutions have been suggested on other posts, however, I have not found a question/answer that addresses the problem with these constraints.

It would be okay to use something else but `display: absolute` on the second child, like a negative margin, but I couldn't get this to work either.

If anyone knows if this is even possible or has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

To see it in action here is my code, simplified to demonstrate the issue:

```css
body{
  color: white;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper .a{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrapper .b{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  min-width: 40px;
}
.wrapper .c{
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to the left of your div because it's been taken out of the [flow](https://youtu.be/P6UgYq3J3Qs) of the document. In fact, it's actually positioned relative to the viewport and not the parent wrapper. To make it positioned to the wrapper, set `position: relative` to the wrapper class to create a [new containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block)

To ensure it overlaps the end of div 'a' I've used the 'right' property to move the right hand edge leftwards by a value that I've set usnig a [custom property](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-custom-properties/) that I've set to both that and div 'c'. See annotated example below.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  --element-c-width: 40px; /* set this to both set the width of div 'c' and how far we move div 'b' leftwards */
}

.a {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  min-width: 40px;
  right: var(--element-c-width); /* from the right hand side of the wrapper div, move it leftwards by this value */
}

.c {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: var(--element-c-width);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it seems so obvious now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Add `position: relative;` to the parent

When an element is given `position: absolute;` property, it'll be positioned against the nearest parent element with `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` positioning. If it doesn't find it, it'll be positioned against the `body`. In this case, you might want to add `position: relative;` to the `.wrapper` element as it's the reference point for absolute positioning.

### Add a positioning value to the element

By definition, `position: absolute;` element will be *absolutely positioned* with a particular value set. That is, how far away from top, right, bottom, or/and left edges. When you don't provide any value, it'll just be stuck to the top left corner, which is what's happening here.

### Need a set value for the positioning

`position: absolute;` takes an element *out of* a normal content flow. That is, elements around it won't affect its size or positioning; thus *absolute* position. To achieve what you showed in the diagram, you need to specify the width for `.c` element and use the same exact value to position the `.b` element from the right edge.

See the snippet below for reference.

```css
body{
  color: white;
  --width: 80px;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .a{
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrapper .b{
  position: absolute;
  right: var(--width);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  min-width: 40px;
}
.wrapper .c{
  background-color: green;
  width: var(--width);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions are using hard coded values to define the width and the position which is not suitable if you have a dynamic content. Here is an idea without hard coded values.

```css
.wrapper{
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto; /* 3 columns */
}
.wrapper > * {
  grid-row: 1; /* all the items at the first and only  row */
}
.wrapper .a{
  grid-column: 1/-1; /* take all the columns  */
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrapper .b{
  grid-column: 2; /* second column */
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  min-width: 40px;
}
.wrapper .c{
  grid-column: 3; /* third column */
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">CCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">BBBBBBBB</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```